# position fixed inner div not scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have this html and css. The problem is I want to scroll inner div but position fixed should not be removed.

```css
  body { 
                position: fixed;
            }
            div {
                overflow-y: scroll;
                height:100%;
            }
```

```html
<body>
        <div>
        Sohail Hussain
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS

        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        ABCDEFGHI
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/k2212qaz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `%` height to work the parent element needs a height. In your case `<html>` and `<body>` do not have a height.

and it's not a good practice to change the positioning of `<body>`. Better wrap your content in a `<div>` and adjust it's positioning instead.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: fixed;
}
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Sohail Hussain
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>FDSFSDFDSFS
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>FDSFSDFDSFS
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>FDSFSDFDSFS
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>FDSFSDFDSFS
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>FDSFSDFDSFS
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>FDSFSDFDSFS

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>ABCDEFGHI
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Just one more question if I want to add some bouncy effects on a div, I am adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; sometimes the scrolling gets stucked. Any resolution of it?

Comment: @sohail.hussain.dyn for that, you may ask new question (try researching before posting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `height: 100vh` on `div` for window height or you need to apply `height: 100%` on body to

```css
body {position: fixed;}
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Sohail Hussain
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    FDSFSDFDSFS

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    ABCDEFGHI
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Percentage height in the div also need to be adjusted the height 100% for your parents div. To simply use:

```
body{
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Here's the example:

```css
body { 
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
        Sohail Hussain
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        FDSFSDFDSFS

        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        ABCDEFGHI
        </div>
```